# GLSL texcoords interpolating unevenly on OSX with OpenGL 3.2/GLSL 1.5

Tags: macos, opengl, glsl

I'm trying to implement a bicubic interpolation shader in OpenGL 3.2/GLSL 1.5. I've tried this on a 2011 15" MBP running OSX 10.7 and a 2013 27" iMac running OSX 10.8 and both have a similar issue.

My shader program works great... except when my window is at certain sizes some of the rows and/or columns of pixels are strangely off. You can check out this screenshot to see what I mean: http://angusforbes.com/texcoord_issue.png. In this image the value of the texCoord.x along the y-axis is not always the same.

So, why are the texcoords uneven? That is, if for example I'm interpolating from 0.0 to 1.0 in the x-axis along a particular row, I would expect that the varying y would be exactly the same. Likewise, if interpolating along the y-axis, the varying x should be the same.

But sometimes they aren't.

Here's some simplified (but working) example code to explain what I mean:

```
#version 150

uniform sampler2D tex0; //some image I'm trying to do bicubic interpolation on
uniform int tWidth; //width of image;
uniform int tHeight; //height of image

in vec2 texCoord; //my interpolated texture coordinates, 0.0->1.0 in each direction                           
out vec4 outputFrag;

void main() {

  float a = fract( texCoord.x * tWidth ); 
  float b = fract( texCoord.y * tHeight );

  outputFrag = vec4( a, b, 0.0, 1.0 );

  /*    
  //it's a little easier to see the issue like this:

  if (a > 0.95) {
    outputFrag = vec4( a, b, 0.0, 1.0 );
  } else {
    outputFrag = vec4( 0.0 );
  }
  */
}
```

I've tried replacing the fract function with: float a = texCoord.x * tWidth - floor(texCoord.x * tWidth); just to see if it was something wonky with the built-in fract method. But it gives the same results.

The reason it matters is that it messes up my shader and is causing odd streaking when suddenly the value I've calculated (based off of my texCoord) at a particular position is 0.01 instead of 0.99 or whatever. I've tried setting "precision highp float;" on the fragment shader, but it doesn't solve the issue. I'm using GL_NEAREST for the min and max filters.

Any ideas? Or is this a normal float-point error that occurs when interpolating texcoords on a shader?

Comment: What triangles are you drawing?

Comment: Hi - I'm drawing two triangles that stretch from -1 to +1 (in clip space -- modelview and projection are identity). The 4 coords are: (-1,-1),(-1,+1),(+1,-1),(+1,+1) and I'm passing in indicies to draw the triangles like this: (0,1,2) and then (2,1,3). So: LowerLeft, UpperLeft, LowerRight for Triangle 1, and LowerRight, UpperLeft, UpperRight for Triangle 2. Pretty basic full screen quad.

Comment: Hmm let me try changing the winding order...

Comment: Nope, no luck with that (changing winding order of second triangle).